# What is the [shuttle-shuttle] tag for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Title pretty much says it all.

What is the [shuttle-shuttle] tag for? How is it different from [space-shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-shuttle)?

Comment: It's probably *not* these shuttle-shuttles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Carrier_Aircraft

Comment: It's only used in https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/did-nasa-archive-the-audio-recording-of-sts-launches, so maybe it can just be removed?

Comment: @BlueCoder Removed.

Comment: I think that was the vehicle Duran Duran used in their last tour

Comment: I think is a synoim of space shuttle. Someone just doesn't know what there talking about @Organic Marble

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch the problem was resolved about 5 years ago.